# Retrieve the current font, scale it, and change the font to that version

Tags: fonts, scaling, plain-tex

I'm using Plain TeX (and `eplain`, if that matters). I would like to be able to generically scale the current font, no matter how the current font has been set. For example, I want to write a macro

```
\def\VandV{V\hskip-3pt{\abitsmallerthanthecurrentfont\&\hskip-3ptV}
```

and I want `\abitsmallerthanthecurrentfont` to make the ampersand a bit smaller.

IIRC, In LaTeX, without packages, one can use `\Large` and `\tiny` and such to affect the size of the current font. But I'm not using LaTeX.

Can this be done in a straightforward way without oodles of modifications to Plain TeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a completely different approach:

```
\input eplain
\beginpackages
  \usepackage{graphicx}
\endpackages

\def\smallampersand{\scalebox{.8}{\&}}
\def\VandV{V\kern-.4ex\smallampersand\kern-.4ex V}

\font\my="Linux Libertine O" at 36pt

\my\VandV
```

---

[image]

---

Note that for a logo `\kern` should be used, or an `\hbox` around the construction, as `\hskip` introduces a break point.

Comment: This is the right way to do what I want to do (the V&V logo). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar approach to @morbusg's: examine the `\fontname`. The following code retrieves the current font name and its size/scaling factor, then modifies the latter and declares a temporary font with the new size. The font is scaled by 1.2 in both directions. As a result the macro can be used recursively to get relatively bigger/smaller sizes. The font manipulation is done in a group to not accumulate the computational error.

```
\newcount\fontscale
\newdimen\fontsize

\def\discard#1\relax{}
\def\processfont#1 #2#3 #4 {%
  \def\fname{#1}%
  % Can't normally compare to 'at' here, because \fontname returns
  % characters of catcode 12
  \if a#2%
    \fontsize=#4
  \else
    \fontscale=#4
  \fi
  \discard}
\def\scalefont#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\x{\fontname\font\space scaled 1000 \relax}%
    \fontscale=0
    \expandafter\processfont\x
    \ifnum\fontscale=0
      % We have the "at" syntax
      \multiply\fontsize by #1
      \divide\fontsize by #2
      \font\tmpfont=\fname\space at \the\fontsize
    \else
      % We have the "scaled" syntax
      \multiply\fontscale by #1
      \divide\fontscale by #2
      \font\tmpfont=\fname\space scaled \the\fontscale
    \fi
    \tmpfont #3%
  \endgroup}
\def\smaller#1{\scalefont{5}{6}{#1}}
\def\bigger#1{\scalefont{6}{5}{#1}}


test \bigger{test \bigger{test \bigger{test}}}

test \smaller{test \smaller{test \smaller{test}}}

\bye
```

[image]

However, this approach can't use different optical font sizes, which are the key to finest typesetting. Accounting for the optical sizes would require infrastructure that needs to know the different available optical sizes of the particular font in use, much like LaTeX already does. Therefore you might achieve better results with LaTeX and, for example, the [`relsize`](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize) package.

Answer (score 1):

I had such a clever idea: to use the result of `\fontname\font` as the input for a macro which loads `\dimexpr`ed smaller font. But unfortunately it has issues (I used plain XeTeX):

```
\font\test="Myriad Pro" at 16pt
\test
\def\smaller{%
  \def\loadnewfont"##1" ##2 ##3\relax{%
    \font\test="##1" at \the\dimexpr##3-1pt\relax\test}
  \expandafter\loadnewfont\fontname\font\relax\&}
\fontname\font
\smaller \fontname\font \smaller \fontname\font
\smaller \fontname\font \smaller \fontname\font
\smaller \fontname\font % the size has vanished with the last call!?
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: **NOTE:** It seems that the 11pt rule only applies to, e.g., Minion Pro and Myriad Pro, but not to, e.g., TeX Gyre Pagella, so that would need another test in there somewhere.